# How can I prevent my bluetooth keyboard from sleeping?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth

I like to type using a bluetooth keyboard.  After about 5 or 10 minutes of being idle, the keyboard seems to go to sleep.  Once the keyboard is asleep, there is a 5 to 10 second delay between the next key press and when it registers on the computer.  I presume this is so that wake up and pair with my laptop again.  Is there any way to configure how much time to wait until the keyboard sleeps, or disable the keyboard sleeping all together?

Comment: This thread might be helpful to you. http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=2704